# A part of my .emacs sometimes takes effect, sometimes doesn't

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, auctex

A use Emacs 24 on an Ubuntu computer. The following are  parts of my .emacs file.

This is for activating flyspell:

```
(autoload 'flyspell-mode "flyspell" "On-the-fly spelling checker." t)
(autoload 'flyspell-delay-command "flyspell" "Delay on command." t)
(autoload 'tex-mode-flyspell-verify "flyspell" "" t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

This defines a key binding for running Auctex Latex:

```
(defun my-run-latex ()
  (interactive)
  (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file))
  (TeX-command "LaTeX" 'TeX-master-file -1))


(defun my-LaTeX-hook ()
 (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-a") 'my-run-latex))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-LaTeX-hook)
```

This one raises the Emacs window when using Latex reverse search:

```
 (defun raise-client-frame ()
      (let ((wmctrl (executable-find "wmctrl")))
        (if wmctrl
        (start-process "wmctrl" nil wmctrl "-R" (frame-parameter nil 'name)))))
    ;; This raises the frame when using Evince.
    (add-hook 'TeX-source-correlate-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (TeX-evince-dbus-p)
              (dbus-register-signal
               :session nil "/org/gnome/evince/Window/0"
               "org.gnome.evince.Window" "SyncSource"
               (lambda (file linecol &rest ignored)
             (TeX-source-correlate-sync-source file linecol ignored)
             (raise-client-frame))))))
    ;; This raises the frame when using all other viewers.
    (add-hook 'server-switch-hook 'raise-client-frame)
```

The problem is that these three sometimes work and sometimes don't and this seems to be random. When they work, all three work and when they don't, none. Whether they work or not is somehow decided at Emacs startup but I don't know how.

Comment: Define "*work*". Describe the symptoms you see when they don't work, and what you expected instead.

Comment: For the record, `C-c C-a` is by default bound to `TeX-command-run-all`, which is a pretty useful function.  Users are advised to use key-bindings of the type `C-c <letter>` in order to avoid clash with the default ones.

Comment: Not working means that they don't take effect. I get error messages that "C-c C-a is undefined", Emacs window won't raise when doing inverse search AND I have  to activate flyspell "by hand".

Comment: That usually happens if there's an error earlier in your Emacs configuration.

Comment: As lunaryorn said, you probably have an error earlier in your configuration, but without more details we can't say what's going on for sure (since the error is unlikely to be in the code you posted).  Check your messages buffer to see if there's anything helpful in there, and maybe post the code preceding what you've already shown us and following those bits that still work when these don't (if there are any).

Comment: I moved the above lines to the top of the .emacs file and the problem seems to be resolved now. I didn't get any error massages in the message buffer.